# Checking the existence of a pattern in a given prefix

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, bioinformatics, suffix-trees

I need to design an algorithm that given a string $T$ of length $n$, performs $O(n)$ preprocessing, and can then answer queries of the sort "does a string $P$ of length $m$ appear in $T$ before position $k$" in time $O(m)$. The algorithm should use a suffix tree.

Unfortunately there are not any good bioinformatics books with fair examples and practical methodologies. Dan Gusfield's book does not offer a solution manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that in a suffix tree for $T$, each leaf corresponds to a suffix of $T$, and is labeled by its position. Furthermore, each internal vertex corresponds to a common prefix of some suffixes of $T$. We label each internal vertex with the minimal position of a suffix covered by it.

Construct a suffix tree for $T$, and augment it by labeling the internal vertices as described above. Given a pattern $P$, traverse the suffix tree to find the vertex corresponding to $P$ (it might correspond to some extension of $P$), and check whether the minimal position written there implies that $P$ occurs before position $k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful